# He is getting to be a naughty boy

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

When "get" is followed by an infinitive, it means "manage" or "have an opportunity".

> He is getting to be a naughty boy.

It means "he manages to be a naughty boy" or "he has an opportunity to be naughty boy".

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

No. *Getting to be* is a different idiom from those two meanings. It means *becoming*, or *starting to be*, or *increasingly being*. It's usually in a continuous form (*is/was getting to be*), though it does occur in other tenses.

Comment: Ex: (he is starting to be a naughty boy) right?

Comment: Yes. Or "he is becoming naughtier".